# Generate a Connected Graph java

Tags: java, random, graph-theory

I want to write a function, which is given a set of vertices and then develops an edge between 2 vertices and repeats this until the graph becomes a connected graph). How can I tell when the graph has become connected?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand this problem. Could you post what you have tried so far?

Comment: Should the edges be directed/undirected? Are the number of edges to be added restricted to a certain number?

Comment: We need more information... However, you can check whether a graph is connected using Dijkstra's algorithm: If by the end of it you still have a node with +inf distance, then it is not connected yet.

Comment: As data structure that you can develop, you can use an adjacency list vector, for which express relationships between a node and others by adding an array corresponding edges of the node.

Comment: You should look into variations on the "[disjoint set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure)" data structure, which is commonly used in graph theory applications for tracking how graphs are divided into connected components.  This can support more efficient algorithms than alternatives depending on graph searching for checking node connectedness.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a basic idea: Every time you add a new edge, you run BFS or DFS to check the connectivity. This solution is can be further optimized.

```
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;

import org.jgrapht.graph.DefaultEdge;
import org.jgrapht.graph.SimpleGraph;

public class Main {

public static boolean isConnected(SimpleGraph<Integer, DefaultEdge> graph) {
    Set<Integer> vertexSet = graph.vertexSet();
    if(vertexSet.size()==0) {
        //graph is connected by definition
        return true;
    }

    if(vertexSet.size()-1>graph.edgeSet().size()) {
        //not enough edges, must be disconnected
        return false;
    }

    Set<Integer> traversed = new HashSet<>();
    Deque<DefaultEdge> toTraverse = new LinkedList<DefaultEdge>();

    //pick one random element to start search
    Integer startVertex = vertexSet.iterator().next();

    traversed.add(startVertex);
    graph.edgesOf(startVertex).forEach(x->toTraverse.addLast(x));
    while(traversed.size()!=vertexSet.size() && toTraverse.size()!=0) {
        DefaultEdge currentEdge = toTraverse.pollFirst();
        Integer src = graph.getEdgeSource(currentEdge);
        Integer dst = graph.getEdgeSource(currentEdge);

        //it can be at most one new vertex
        Integer targetVertex = traversed.contains(src)?dst:src;
        if(!traversed.contains(targetVertex)) {
            traversed.add(targetVertex);
            //BFS
            graph.edgesOf(targetVertex).forEach(x->toTraverse.addLast(x));

            //DFS
            //graph.edgesOf(targetVertex).forEach(x->toTraverse.addFirst(x));
        }
    }

    if(traversed.size()==vertexSet.size()) {
        return true;
    }else {
        return false;
    }
}

public static SimpleGraph<Integer, DefaultEdge> buildGraph(int numberOfVertices) {
    SimpleGraph<Integer, DefaultEdge> g =
            new SimpleGraph<Integer, DefaultEdge>(DefaultEdge.class);
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfVertices; i++) {
        g.addVertex(i);
    }
    Random r = new Random();
    do {
        int a = r.nextInt(numberOfVertices);
        int b = r.nextInt(numberOfVertices);
        while(a == b) {
            b = r.nextInt(numberOfVertices);
        }
        g.addEdge(a, b);
    }while(!isConnected(g));
    return g;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleGraph<Integer, DefaultEdge> g = buildGraph(10);
    System.out.println("Number of edges");
    System.out.println(g.edgeSet().size());
    System.out.println("Edges:");
    for(DefaultEdge e: g.edgeSet()){
        String a = g.getEdgeSource(e).toString();
        String b = g.getEdgeTarget(e).toString();
        System.out.println(a+" "+b);
    }
}

}
```

For an arbitrary graph, checking connectivity requires at least O(V) (V - number of vertices, E - number of edges). BFS and DFS run in O(V+E). This might be fine if you want to create relatively small graphs. Here is a smarter idea how to do it. At the beginning you create V separate graphs. Now you want to add edge between A and B, you find the graph where A belongs and the other where B belongs. If those are two different graphs, merge them. Repeat this process until only one graph remains.